# Automatic update of database

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables ..shirts, pants and shoes..
with the same structures (id, receipt_id, item, quantity, price,total).

I have this 3 queries to compute the total price in every table and and computation of all table.

---

```
select SUM(total) AS tot_shirts from shirts

select SUM(total) AS tot_pants from pants

select SUM(total) AS tot_shoes from shoes
```

Which looks like this

```
$total_income = $tot_shirts + $tot_pants + $tot_shoes;
```

---

And I have a table named "today_income". with columns(id, date, total)

The problem is I don't know how update the table "today_income" column "total" with $total_income every time there is a new record is inserted..

How can I do that?

Comment: Just a note: is there some reason for storing the data in different tables? Since they have the same structure it's much better to have one table for all, especially for future needs (what if you start selling belts?)

Answer (score 1):

Create Trigger on that tables.
Run the trigger whenever new insert is made on the tables.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need this 
`UPDATE today_income set total = $total_income` 
But need 
`INSERT INTO today_income(total) VALUES($total_income)`
And if you need to update `total_income` even after inserting without using php i.e. directly using mysql clients then you should Create TRIGGER.

> http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/triggers/after_insert.php

Answer (score 0):

> every time there is a new record inserted

By the look of it, a trigger on insert is the most viable thing you can do. You could make sure you never forget to do it on every query that may insert in the table, but you surely do not want to be in the more-than-realistic scenario in which you forgot it at once place.